# Is there a way to limit request frequency and sizes out of the box in ktor?

Tags: ktor

Simply, I have methods like `post("/login") { ... }`  and `post("/uploadAvatarImage") { ... }`, and I want to limit the sizes appropriately. If I were to hand roll this myself, I could either find some way to hook into every request and throw if a rolling rate is higher than acceptable, or create overrides of `post` to include things like rate limit and size restrictions. It would be nice if this were all definable globally in some of the configuration sections, so I don't have to manually check whether a user supplied a 2 billion character user name.

Is this a feature that exists in ktor? Or anyone have a good example of a nice way to do it, if there exists something better than what I was thinking?

Comment: Do you mean to limit the size of a POST body?

Comment: Well, any body I suppose. It would be nice to say at a high level "no request should exceed 3kb unless I specify otherwise on the handler".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about limiting the size, I am assuming in the body of these requests you are deserialising to some kind of data class? If so the `valiktor` library [(link)](https://github.com/valiktor/valiktor) makes this very easy to add a max size limit on a particular property.

In regards to rate limiting, I wouldn't really expect this from the framework itself, however it seems someone has made a feature for this [(link)](https://github.com/mantono/ktor-rate-limiting).

It is interesting I mean Spring Boot itself doesn't have rate limiting either but rather its competitor to nginx, Spring Cloud Gateway, has a rate limiting feature. It kind of poses the question of whether it is necessary to think about the architecture of introducing rate limiting at another layer (such as a gateway entry point) before reaching your app.